# Twitter oAuth authentication in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, twitter-oauth

I want to authenticate user using Twitter oAuth framework to get oAuth string and Consumer key. But I don’t want to include the whole framework as Only I want to authenticate user don’t want to share or tweet using oAuth on twitter.
Please help me guys

Comment: [Refer this](https://dev.twitter.com/node/3240/backlinks)

Comment: @LithuT.V This will work on iOS too?

Comment: Not sure if webservice is available it can do i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [OAuth.io](https://oauth.io) with the [IOS SDK](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-ios) for this purpose.

It works easily for more than 90 providers as Twitter and it's lightweight (~33kb).